# Rhino JS NativeArray types

Tags: java, jvm, rhino

I've been experimenting with the Rhino -> Java interoperability and have run across something that I can't quite explain.

I'm invoking a script from Java, coercing the result into a Java object, then retrieving the results.

In my JS:

```
this.objectmap.put("list", [1,1,2,3,5]);
```

Setting a breakpoint on the NativeArray constructor, I see that the object array that gets passed in looks as follows:

```
[1.0,1.0,2,3,5]
```

Where 1.0 are of type Double and 2,3,5 are of type Integer.

Any idea why this happens? I can't seem to track down the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript (or rather ECMA Script) does not have a concept of an integer.  It just has the concept of a "Number" this may happen to contain an integral value or a real value (floating point).  Both are stored as a real value in a variable and therefore in memory.

So in order for it to be converted to Java code it uses the "double" type to represent it as that is the closest representation it can make.

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf  (the specification and section 8.5 The Number Type, 9.3 toNumber)

Note these specs relate to version 5 (of the ECMA standard) which is probably not what Rhino implements, so you may want to look on the website for the spec that matches your ECMA implemented version, but this matter has been the same since the language was invented.

So knowing the above it is possible for integer values to be promoted to a "double" type when interoperating with any JavaScript/ECMA engine.

Comment: Thanks for the info. You're absolutely right -- *most* of my JS numerical values are of type double when handling them in Java. It's only in the case when I use an array to the types start to get mixed.